# get data from two different urls to the same ScrapyItem()

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new at scrapy and I've been trying to scrape this website: https://quotes.toscrape.com/

The datas I want is

- quote;
- author;
- date of birth and
- local of birth.

To get the first 2 datas (quote and author), I have to scrape from

https://quotes.toscrape.com/

But to get the other 2 (date of birth and local of birth) I have to go to "about author":

`https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/[NAME OF THE AUTHOR\]`

My `items.py` code is:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesItem(scrapy.Item):
quote = scrapy.Field()
author = scrapy.Field()
date_birth = scrapy.Field()
local_birth = scrapy.Field()
```

and `quotesipder.py` code is:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotesItem  


class QuotespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotespider"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_items= QuotesItem()

        quotes = response.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-8']/div")

        for quote in quotes:
            all_items['quote'] = quote.xpath("./span[@class='text']/text()").get()
            all_items['author'] = quote.xpath("./span[2]/small/text()").get()
            # Here we get the first 2 datas.


            about = quote.xpath("./span[2]/small/following-sibling::a/@href").get()
            url_about = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + about  # URL to go to 'about author'.


            yield response.follow(url_about, callback=self.about_autor,
                                  cb_kwargs={'items': all_items})
            
            yield item


    def about_autor(self, response, items):  # Should get the other two datas (date_birth, local_bith)

        item['date_birth '] = response.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/p[1]/span[1]/text()").get()
        item['local_bith '] = response.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/p[1]/span[2]/text()").get()


        yield item
```

I have tried it using `cb_kwargs` parameter, like in the code `quotespider.py`, but it didn't work.

**This is what I get:**

```
[
{"quote": "quote1", 
"autor": "author1",  
"date_birth": "",
 "local_birth": ""}, # Empty for the first 10 items
...
{"quote":"quote10", 
"autor": "author10", 
"date_birth": "", 
"local_birth": ""}, # 10th element also empty

{"quote":"quote10", 
"autor": "author10", 
"date_birth": "December 16, 1775", 
"local_birth": "in Steventon"},  # 10th element *repeated* with wrong date_birth and local_birth 

{"quote": "quote10", 
"autor": "author10", 
"date_birth": "June 01, 1926", 
"local_birth": "United States"}, # 10th element *repeated* with wrong date_birth and local_birth
```

No `local_birth` or `date_birth` were added to the first 10 quotes (added in parse function), but the last quote is repeated with all 'local<sub>-</sub>birth' and 'date<sub>-</sub>birth'.

**What i expected is to get is something like:**

```
[{'quote': 'quote1',
'author': 'author1',
'date_birth': 'date_birth1',
'local_birth': 'local_birth1'},

{'quote': 'quote2',
'author': 'author2',
'date_birth': 'date_birth2',
'local_birth': 'local_birth2'},

{'quote': 'quote3',
'author': 'author3',
'date_birth': 'date_birth3',
'local_birth': 'local_birth'},
]
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe some pages don't have this information. Did you check pages?

Comment: in `parse()` don't use `yield item` - you don't have variable `item` in `parse()` and it may raise error. Besides you sends `all_items` from `parse` to `about_author` and it use `yield item` to send result.

Comment: better use `all_items= QuotesItem()` inside `for`-loop - to create new, empty item for new data. If you don't create new item then it may have old values (from previous loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of typos in your code that need fixing such as in the `about_autor` method you pass in items and then the variable used in the method body is item.  Also their is a `yield item` statement below your `yield response.follow` call in your `parse` method that would certainly throw an error.

But beyond that there are few additional notes I will make.

- When iterating a selector group you should move the item initialization to inside of the loop that way you are yielding a unique item on each yield and not overwriting the previous values of the same item.
- `cb_kwargs` stands for callback keyword arguments, so the second parameter in `about_autor` should be a keyword argument.
- since the quotes site features multiple quotes from the same author, you should add the `dont_filter=True` parameter to your call to `response.follow` so it doesn't filter duplicates when requesting an authors page more than once.

This seemed to work fine for me.

Example:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesItem(scrapy.Item):
    quote = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    date_birth = scrapy.Field()
    local_birth = scrapy.Field()

class QuotespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotespider"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://quotes.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath("//div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-8']/div")
        for quote in quotes:
            item= QuotesItem()
            item['quote'] = quote.xpath("./span[@class='text']/text()").get()
            item['author'] = quote.xpath("./span[2]/small/text()").get()
            # Here we get the first 2 datas.
            about = quote.xpath("./span[2]/small/following-sibling::a/@href").get()
            url_about = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + about  # URL to go to 'about author'.
            yield response.follow(url_about, callback=self.about_autor,
                                  cb_kwargs={'item': item}, dont_filter=True)

    def about_autor(self, response, item={}):  # Should get the other two datas (date_birth, local_bith)
        item['date_birth'] = response.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/p[1]/span[1]/text()").get()
        item['local_birth'] = response.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/p[1]/span[2]/text()").get()
        yield item
```

OUTPUT

```
{'author': 'Steve Martin',
 'date_birth': 'August 14, 1945',
 'local_birth': 'in Waco, Texas, The United States',
 'quote': '“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling/>
{'author': 'J.K. Rowling',
 'date_birth': 'July 31, 1965',
 'local_birth': 'in Yate, South Gloucestershire, England, The United Kingdom',
 'quote': '“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more '
          'than our abilities.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt/>
{'author': 'Eleanor Roosevelt',
 'date_birth': 'October 11, 1884',
 'local_birth': 'in The United States',
 'quote': '“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until '
          "it's in hot water.”"}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/>
{'author': 'Albert Einstein',
 'date_birth': 'March 14, 1879',
 'local_birth': 'in Ulm, Germany',
 'quote': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It '
          'cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe/>
{'author': 'Marilyn Monroe',
 'date_birth': 'June 01, 1926',
 'local_birth': 'in The United States',
 'quote': "“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be "
          'absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison/>
{'author': 'Thomas A. Edison',
 'date_birth': 'February 11, 1847',
 'local_birth': 'in Milan, Ohio, The United States',
 'quote': "“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”"}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/>
{'author': 'Albert Einstein',
 'date_birth': 'March 14, 1879',
 'local_birth': 'in Ulm, Germany',
 'quote': '“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/>
{'author': 'Albert Einstein',
 'date_birth': 'March 14, 1879',
 'local_birth': 'in Ulm, Germany',
 'quote': '“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though '
          'nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a '
          'miracle.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide/>
{'author': 'André Gide',
 'date_birth': 'November 22, 1869',
 'local_birth': 'in Paris, France',
 'quote': '“It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for '
          'what you are not.”'}
2023-11-22 15:56:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen/>
{'author': 'Jane Austen',
 'date_birth': 'December 16, 1775',
 'local_birth': 'in Steventon Rectory, Hampshire, The United Kingdom',
 'quote': '“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a '
          'good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! It works for me too. Btw, I appreciate your tips, as I said, I'm new at this so any tips are welcome :) If i may ask one more thing... Why did you put 'item=None'?

Comment: YW.  Because `item=None` makes it a keyword argument, with None being the default., I suppose I could have put `item={}`  but it really doesn't make a difference since you are always passing a scrapy item as the item the default is never actually used in this example. @GabrielLucena

Comment: got it! now i'm understanding better how items and cb_kargs works. thanks, man.